# Non recursive copy/delete operations using SHFILEOPSTRUCT

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using the SHFILEOPSTRUCT for deleting/Copying file operation. In case of recursive operation it works well. But for Non recursive option (FOF_NORECURSION) I dont see any effect. Basically the operation works the same even if FOF_NORECURSION flag is set or not set.

```
SHFILEOPSTRUCT fileop = { 0 };
    fileop.wFunc = FO_COPY;
    fileop.pFrom = pszFrom;
    fileop.pTo = pszTo;

    fileop.fFlags = FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_NO_UI;
    fileop.fFlags |= FOF_NORECURSION;
    int res = SHFileOperationW( &fileop );
```

can you please suggest the right way to handle Non recursive operation ?

Comment: There is a comment in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759795.aspx) that says *It seems that if you specify `FOF_NOCONFIRMATION`, `FOF_NORECURSION` will have no effect*. Looks like you hit the same problem.

Comment: Quote: "File deletion is recursive unless you set the FOF_NORECURSION flag".  You are not deleting files.  If you don't want to copy sub-directories then use FOF_FILESONLY.

Comment: File Deletion doesn't ever work Non recursive. Even if you set the flag FOF_NORECURSION or not... I tried all possible options. But it always deletes the folder.